# return acf image src in twig

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields

i cant get the acf images to return.

in my single-work.twig (view file) i have

`<img src="{‌{ Image(post.meta(‘laptop_image')).src }}" />`

and in the single-work.php (controller file) template i have

`$context[‘laptop_image'] = get_field(‘laptop_image’);`

i also tried

in single-work.php (controller file)

`$post->laptop_image = new Timber\Image($post->laptop_image);`

in single-work.twig (view file)

`<img src="{‌{ post.laptop_image.src | resize(500, 300) }}" />`

most of the time i get “unknown” as the result.. I used to get the image id returned but i cant remember how i got that… Any help would be great.

full single-work.php

```
$context         = Timber::context();
$timber_post     = Timber::query_post();
$context['post'] = $timber_post;
$context['text_with_image_title'] = get_field('headline');
$context['text_with_image_text'] = get_field('description');
$post->laptop_image = new Timber\Image($post->laptop_image);
$context['ipad_image'] = get_field('ipad_image');
$context['iphone_image'] = get_field('iphone_image');
$context['text_with_image_btn_link'] = get_field('work_url'); 
$context['text_with_image_btn_label'] = 'Go to ' . $timber_post->post_title . ' Website';
$context['text_with_image_btn_target'] = '_blank';

if ( post_password_required( $timber_post->ID ) ) {
    Timber::render( 'single-password.twig', $context );
} else {
    Timber::render( array( 'single-' . $timber_post->ID . '.twig', 'single-' . $timber_post->post_type . '.twig', 'single-' . $timber_post->slug . '.twig', '/pages/single-work.twig' ), $context );
}


var_dump($post->laptop_image); //returns image id
```

full code of work.twig

```
<div class="col-6 text-with-image__column text-with-image__column--image">
    <div class="text-with-image__wrapper">

        <img src="{{ post.laptop_image.src | resize(500, 300) }}" />

        {{dump(post.laptop_image)}} //returns nothing


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i realized i was using a macro and therefore

`<img src="{‌{ Image(post.laptop_image).src }}" />` works fine, though it needs to be applied as the macro value of the new instance. Not just apart of the template.